# Checking existence of set element matching predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method

```
- (BOOL)isLockedDueToSamples
{
    if ([self.samples count] > 0)
    {
        NSPredicate* p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"appraised == YES OR analysed == YES"];
        if ([[self.samples filteredSetUsingPredicate:p] count] > 0)
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This method needs to be called pretty frequently but is quite slow since self.samples can be up to 1500. Is there a technique for checking for the existence of an set element matching the predicate without having to filter the whole set?

EDIT:

I've managed to make the method slightly faster like this

```
- (BOOL)isLockedDueToSamples
{
    if ([self.samples count] > 0)
    {
        for (Sample *sample in self.samples)
        {
            if (sample.appraised || sample.analysed)
            {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You could try objectsPassingTest:, but I don't think that will be any faster than your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, you could do the filtering asynchronously, or use [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`objectsPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_34) method, passing it a block to test on, and stop if/when you encounter a positive test:

```
- (BOOL)isLockedDueToSamples
{
    NSSet* matches = [self.samples objectsPassingTest:^(id sample, BOOL* stop){
        if (sample.appraised || sample.analysed) {
            *stop = YES;
            return YES;
        }
    }];

    return [matches count] > 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

I don't believe that this will be any faster than your for loop, however.